# Find the limit as $z$ goes to $i\pi$ for the function $e^z + z^2$ (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Find the following limit: $\lim_{z\rightarrow i\pi} e^z+z^2$

In this problem we are asked to simplify as much as possible. My thought process is that if z is $i\pi$, then $z^2=-\pi^2$ and then $e^z=-1$. Does this mean the limit is just $-\pi^2-1$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.